# How to fix a warning in pytest?

Tags: python, django, testing, pytest, pytest-django

I do tests using py test. There is some kind of warning in the terminal, so I could just skip it, but I would like to remove it from the terminal.

```
RemovedInDjango50Warning: The USE_L10N setting is deprecated. Starting with Djan
go 5.0, localized formatting of data will always be enabled. For example Django will display numbers and dates using the format of the current locale.
    warnings.warn(USE_L10N_DEPRECATED_MSG, RemovedInDjango50Warning)
```

Help me, please!!!!!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HPWN.png)

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your Python script, add the following 2 lines of code:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings(action="ignore")
```

This will hide all warnings from the terminal.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you, it helped! It was necessary to add these lines to the project settings

Answer (score 0):

Use ignore options for pytest:

```bash
pytest -W ignore::DeprecationWarning -W ignore::PendingDeprecationWarning
```

Or add lines bellow to pytest.ini:

```ini
[pytest]
filterwarnings =
    ignore::DeprecationWarning
    ignore::PendingDeprecationWarning
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Django 5.0 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/5.0/), `USE_L10N` is removed in Django 5 which is still a development version at the moment and the latest [pytest](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest) compares your Django 4 or below version with Django 5, then gives the warning.

So, you should put the code below to `[pytest]` in [pytest.ini](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/customize.html#pytest-ini) to ignore the warning. *You can see [Controlling warnings](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/capture-warnings.html#controlling-warnings):

```ini
# "pytest.ini"

[pytest] # ↓ Here ↓
filterwarnings =
    ignore::DeprecationWarning
```

Or, you should run the command below to ignore the warning:

```
pytest -W ignore::DeprecationWarning
```

In addition, putting the code below to `[pytest]` in `pytest.ini` can disable all warnings. *You can see [the doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/capture-warnings.html#disabling-warning-capture-entirely)

```ini
# "pytest.ini"

[pytest] # ↓ Here ↓
addopts = -p no:warnings
```

And, running the command below can disable all warnings. *You can see [the doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/capture-warnings.html#disabling-warnings-summary):

```
pytest --disable-warnings
```

Answer (score -1):

It was necessary to add these lines to the project settings:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings(action="ignore")
```